# WCF REST service - DataContract stops constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have a strange problem that's happening with my WCF REST service.  For an operation where it accepts data, let's say it accepts the Foo class:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "users/{username}")]
[OperationContract]
public void UpdateLoginUser(string username, LoginUser userUpdated) {
[...]
}
```

Now my LoginUser class inherits from my NormalUser class:

```
<DataContract()> _
Public MustInherit Class NormalUser
[...]
End Class

Public Class LoginUser
 Inherits NormalUser
[...]
End Class
```

When I PUT to my service, triggering UpdateLoginUser, everything works OK.  However, if I apply DataContract to my NormalUser class:

```
<DataContract()> _
Public Class LoginUser
 Inherits NormalUser
[...]
End Class
```

... suddenly, the LoginUser class's constructor doesn't fire during deserialization!  I have business login rules in there I need to run.  So, why is it that when I apply the     DataContract attribute to my inherited class, its constructor stops getting fired?  How can I get around this?  If I want to change namespace or name, I do need to apply the     DataContract attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) does not call the contract's constructor.  If you want a method to run upon deserialization decorate it with the [`OnDeserializing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute.aspx) attrbute:

> When applied to a method, specifies
>   that the method is called during
>   deserialization of an object.

Your other option is to [use `XmlSerializer` with WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx):

> WCF also supports the XmlSerializer
>   class. The XmlSerializer class is not
>   unique to WCF. It is the same
>   serialization engine that ASP.NET Web
>   services use. The XmlSerializer class
>   supports a much narrower set of types
>   than the DataContractSerializer class,
>   but allows much more control over the
>   resulting XML and supports much more
>   of the XML Schema definition language
>   (XSD) standard. It also does not
>   require any declarative attributes on
>   the serializable types. For more
>   information, see the XML Serialization
>   topic in the .NET Framework
>   documentation. The XmlSerializer class
>   does not support data contract types.

Comment: This is a major PITA, because although I can apply OnDeserializing attribute to my constructor methods, what do I do about default values? (eh. Private xyz As String = "abc") - that initialization counts as part of the constructor, right, and it won't get done??

Comment: or use a method with the `[OnDeserialized]` attribute for a method that gets called AFTER the whole thing has been deserialized

Comment: @jez9999: Do the member initialization inside the method as well.  @marc_s: Right on - nice catch.

Answer (score 3):

The DataContract (de)serializer does indeed **NOT** call the constructor.

That sounds odd and crazy - but that's the way it works, and there is no way to change this.

Because of this, the DataContract serializer also does **NOT** require a parameter-less constructor (like XmlSerializer or others).

Marc

Comment: So why is it that if I don't specify DataContract, yet my class INHERITS from a class that does, the class that INHERITS *does* have its constructor called?  :-)  Isn't this totally inconsistent and wacky?

Comment: That's just the way WCF works. The DataContractSerializer will ONLY come into play for classes that have the [DataContract] attribute explicitly on them - it's **NOT** inherited from parent class to child class. That's just the way WCF was designed.